# How do I use Devise with 2 nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to use Devise with 3 models all at once, but I'm feeling a little lost right now with the sign up strategy.

My model looks like this:

`User` has_one `Client` has_one `VIP_Client`

Using `Simple_Form and accepts_nested_attributes_for`, I'm able to create all 3 models at once in the same signup page, but I want to break this into 2 different pages: one for `User-Client` signup, and another one for `User-Client-VIP_Client` signup, because the logic is quite different from one to another - the `VIP_Client` needs a few more validations and all. Problem is, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. How do I make 2 separate forms which builds new `Users` and map to the same `User` resource to save it into the DB using Devise?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than focus on Devise and its models could you use some kind of multi-step form to solve your problem? Check out...

http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=wizard